# Pass URL to XAML at runtime

Tags: c#, xbox360, smf

I want to pass a URL to a SMFPlayer at runtime, is there a way to do this in XAML without Binding ? Instead of statically setting the source like I've done below.

So basically the user clicks a button associated with a specific object. A URL field is extracted and passed to the player.

```
<Core:SMFPlayer x:Name="smf" LogLevel="Error"  LogWriters="ConsoleDebug" RetryInterval="00:00:15" RetryDuration="00:01:00">
    <Core:SMFPlayer.Playlist>
        <Media:PlaylistItem>
            "MediaSource="http://az30243.vo.msecnd.net/ss-video/HawaiiSurfing_H264_EE4_CBR_1080p_Xbox.ism/manifest"
            MediaAssetId="asdf"                 
            DeliveryMethod="AdaptiveStreaming"       
            />
    </Core:SMFPlayer.Playlist>
</Core:SMFPlayer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there is a way to do it in XAML at runtime, but you can do it programmatically at runtime.  In your code behind you can use the following.

```
 Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core.Media.PlaylistItem mp = new    Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core.Media.PlaylistItem();
            mp.MediaSource = strPath;
            smf.CurrentPlaylistItem = mp;
            smf.Play();
```

This way, you can set your strPath to any Uri. Depending on your UI for example, this button plays this video and etc.  Setting each one to a different strPath will let you swap videos in and out.

Comment: Yeah I just did it programatically by wrapping my object in an playlistitem and setting the media source to the expected Uri.